# Extending a Homeomorphism between bounded open subspaces of $R^n$

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I am wondering if the following is true:

> Suppose $U, V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are bounded open subsets. Suppose $h: U \to V$ is a homeomorphism.  Then there exists a homeomorphism $H : \overline{U} \to \overline{V}$ extending $h$.

My gut says this can't be done.  Any insight or reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

$(0,2) - {1}$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1) ∪ (10,11)$, but the closer of the first is [0,2], whereas the closure of the second is $[0,1] ∪ [10,11]$, which are not homeomorphic.
So you are correct; there is no extension in general.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've missed an assumption with my question and instead of editing it have reposted the question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176557/extending-a-homeomorphism-between-open-ball-and-bounded-open-subset-of-rn         Maybe you wouldn't mind having a look