# Extending a Homeomorphism between open ball and bounded open subset of $R^n$

Tags: general-topology

I am wondering if the following is true:

> Suppose $U$ is the unit open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are bounded open set. Suppose $h: U \to V$ is a homeomorphism.  Then there exists a homeomorphism $H : \overline{U} \to \overline{V}$ extending $h$.

Any insight or reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $V\subset\mathbb{C}\equiv\mathbb{R}^2$ defined as 
$$V=\{z\in\mathbb{C} | 1<|z|<2,\arg(z)\neq0\}$$
i.e. an annulus with a radius taken out. Since it is an open simply connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ it is homeomorphic to the open disk, hence there exists a homeomorphism $h$. However this homeomorphism cannot be extended to the closure since $\overline{V}$ is not simply connected.

Comment: Yes, indeed. $\overline{V}$ is a closed annulus, which is not simply connected.

Comment: It is *path connected*, but not [*simply connected*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space).

Comment: sorry I have not studied that yet and I am not getting out anything out from here sorry to bother you

Comment: For your example, what if we assume the boundary of $V$ is a Jordan curve? And related to that: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176580/extending-a-homeomorphism-between-open-ball-and-open-box-of-rn

Comment: I think in that case it can be related to the [*Schoenflies problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem).