# Extending a Homeomorphism between open ball and open box of $R^n$

Tags: general-topology

I am wondering if the following is true:

> Suppose $U$ is the unit open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $V = (0,1)^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $h: U \to V$ is a homeomorphism.  Then there exists a homeomorphism $H : \overline{U} \to \overline{V}$ extending $h$.

Comment: I'd try to use sequences in U with limit in $\overline U$.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not true unless $n=1$.  Take $n=2$ for simplicity (essentially the example works for all $n\ge 2$). Define $f:U\to U$ in polar coordinates by 
$$f(r,\theta) = (r,\theta+1/(1-r))$$
This is a homeomorphism, with the inverse 
$$f^{-1}(r,\theta) = (r,\theta-1/(1-r))$$
But it does not have boundary limits anywhere, so it has no continuous extension to $\overline{U}$.

To get $h:U\to V$, compose $f$ with any reasonable homeomorphism from $U$ onto $V$.

In higher dimensions, use cylindrical coordinates.